# Iphone development viewcontroller portrait to landscape no autorotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I have a viewcontroller that's pushing another vc that should be in landscape mode but it does not autorotate to landscape when pushed ie. still in portrait.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

When a popping the vc and back to the first controller all is perfect, it only displays in portrait mode only.

I can get the second vc to rotate by rotating the phone/emulator and then stick to the autorotate landscape. Then also perfect when popping, returns to portrait mode.

So is there any way to maybe progamaticly rotate the interface to landscape. Have tried using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
```

But to no great success. Statusbar then stuck in landscape when popping.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your `viewDidLoad` method, it should work

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
[self.view setTransform:rotate];

CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320); 
self.view.frame = contentRect; 
[self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f)];
```

Comment: With this approach I have to manually set the statusbar for every view? Because as stated above this solution don't make the statusbar autorotate back to portrait when popping the vc.

Comment: No, when you're popping the view you'll need to rotate the statusbar back to portrait manually

Comment: I get a small space like 1-3px to the left when the view is now landscaped. Have a fullscreen imageview layed out in IB. Is there anyway to get rid of that?