# How to force horizontal orientation for a view inside of a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController in my MainWindow.xib.

Each tab contains a UINavigationController which has a UITableViewController.

When I press a button in the UITableViewController I want to push a view controller onto the navigation stack in horizontal orientation.

I have over-ridden the following in the UITableViewController

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}
```

but the pushed view controller does not appear in horizontal orientation (in the XIB it is defined as landscape).

How can I push it in horizontal orientation?

Comment: Overriding that method does not force to autorotate. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492085/iphone-development-viewcontroller-portrait-to-landscape-no-autorotate/6492166#comment-7634401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorotation for `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` has got some constraints:

1. for UITabBarController, autorotation will work only if all of the controllers in the tab bar support autorotation;
2. for UINavigationController, autorotation will work only if the rootViewController in the UINavigationController supports it.

Once you have ensured that this conditions are met, then you can try and push your UITableViewController having defined its shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLanscape);
}
```

EDIT:

All of your UIViewControllers should have this definition for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

except the one you want to force to landscape, which should have the definition given above.

Also have a look at the last post in [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1940-uitabbar-autorotate.html) to correctly implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for UITabBarController.

Comment: my UITabBarController is part of MainWindow.xib so it is defined in the AppDelegate. The UITabbarController contains a UINavigationController, which contains a UITableViewController. I have implemented shouldAutoRotate in all of the VC's, but still no luck.

Comment: question, apart from pushing your landscape view: when you rotate the device, does the view autorotate? if not, then you have to check something in your code. specifically, the MainWindows UITabBarController also needs to have its `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` defined.

Comment: when rotating the device it does not autorotate. I added your method in my appdelegate (this is where the UITabBarController is connected). no luck.

Comment: Don't know exactly what to think, without seeing your project. Anyway, give a look at my last edit... just in case...

Comment: Modified my code to your edit, unfortunately it does not rotate.

Comment: When I present it modally instead of pushing it onto the view stack it  appears in landscape mode. Interesting.

Comment: Would you try the category trick I suggested for UITabBarController also for UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change status bar orientation in viewWillAppear method and revert in viewWillDisappear etc. also return only landscape orientation in the method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: in which view controller should I be implementing this?

Comment: the one you want in different orientation. like you want viewContoller1 in landscape then apply the code in viewController1

Comment: i tried that, it doesn't work unfortunately. VC1 pushes VC2 which pushes VC3 (i want this to be landscape). All must implement your code, which I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems logical. However, did you try this in the pushed view controller that wants to be landscape only:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
          interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

The idea of this method is to return YES for the orientations you support for a view controller.